How to force refresh server-side component in nexjs?
I have a orders/page.tsx and orders/[id]/page.tsx. Orders page.tsx is just a server side component which has a table that shows name, phone number, total price, status, edit button of orders. id page.tsx opens single order. It is a client side component. Here you can change the status of the order and after clicking Save button, it sends put request to server and router.push('/orders'). But my orders page table still shows old data (with old status). How can I force my orders/page.tsx to fetch new data after changing status in orders/[id]/page.tsx? I don't use redux or mobx

Can you provide information how you're fetching the data in your orders/page.tsx so that we can understand where the problem is coming from, for example, you can share your component with minimal reproducible code.
